# cryptic hexadecimal character printed to file by c++ ofstream

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compilation, hex

I have a C++ implementation for a species tree inference algorithm (https://bitbucket.org/ikramu/mixtreem/). I used the program to generate the results (last used Nov 2015). Recently, a friend complained that the program writes cryptic hexadecimal characters with species tree to the file. When I checked, it turns out that the both cout and ofstream, while writing the output to console/file, prefixes it with hex characters.

Here is an example tree string in wrong format

`(((((gsLeaf_5_0:0x1.f48e471f06272p-3,gsLeaf_2_0:0x1.00dc26e053374p-1):0x1.323ffd29b8957p-1,gsLeaf_6_0:0x1.436dedaff881p-4):0x1.068e0e09d3ca6p-1,(gsLeaf_10_0:0x1.dddd5f73dc5a6p-1,(gsLeaf_0_0:0x1.7d04b4f035256p-4,(gsLeaf_9_0:0x1.c4789873fdf45p-1,gsLeaf_4_0:0x1.2821f2411930ap-6):0x1.9ac119403aff1p-5):0x1.60be9c70541f1p-4):0x1.44ea2f3a28908p-1):0x1.1e32eb27c05e3p-1,(gsLeaf_3_0:0x1.7a654ce448e53p-2,gsLeaf_8_0:0x1.78866bffd867ep-1):0x1.1835719e4a4fdp-3):0x1.5b907f43cbea7p-2,(gsLeaf_1_0:0x1.d517c27fc6fe9p-1,gsLeaf_7_0:0x1.ceaccb3d9531bp-1):0x1.2646ebc79ad1p-2,gsLeaf_11_0:0x1.0c5763dc4bda7p-1);`

Here is a tree string in correct format

`(((gsLeaf_10_0:0.627669,gsLeaf_5_0:0.510248):0.998783,(gsLeaf_2_0:0.862504,gsLeaf_9_0:0.929773):0.109781):0.265052,(((gsLeaf_7_0:0.245532,(gsLeaf_8_0:0.941468,gsLeaf_6_0:0.099485):0.061383):0.002515,gsLeaf_4_0:0.768784):0.417351,gsLeaf_11_0:0.182966):0.848415,((gsLeaf_3_0:0.460478,gsLeaf_0_0:0.082105):0.881017,gsLeaf_1_0:0.451832):0.938306);`

As I have been away from C/C++ for more than a year, I don't know if it is due to some modifications in platform, C++ version, architecture or something else? The code has not been changed since (I compiled and tested older versions of the code as well). Will be grateful for Any ideas/hints?

UPDATE:
I think it has something to do with the way double values are (ill)printed. Please see the attached figure from debugging session. While the value Netbeans show in debugger is -12315.334990286983, the printed value (in Output in the bottom) is  -0x1.80daae0f63389p+13. 
[image]

Comment: Can you trim down the code to a small example to post here? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @zaph I think the code screws in printing "double/float" values. See the figure

Comment: Please delete the comment that was added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it looks like there is hexadecimal in the results but it looks like it is an output formatting issue in sp_tree.output function. Add that code to the question.

Note the each value ends with one of: p-1, p-2, p-3, p-4, p-5, p-6 and neither p or - is a hexadecimap character. Best bet is the specified format can not hangle the data values and defaults to output you are seeing.

See [C++ printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and you will see that the format you are seeing is due to a formatting character: 'a'.

From the documentation:

```
specifier Output                                 Example
a         Hexadecimal floating point, lowercase  0xc.90fep-2
```

Compare to your output: `0x1.d517c27fc6fe9p-1`

Perhaps there is a dynamic format that is causing this output.

Comment: You are bang on! When I used printf(), it prints out the correct value to console. I tried with std::cout.precision(10) in the constructor hoping that I may get the right format but it didn't worked. I wonder if I have to use C-based file operations to get the right output in the file :-(